# Source indexing on static C++ library

Tags: c++, version-control, azure-devops, nuget, lib

I'm trying to create a NuGet package from a static C++ library. I have a build pipeline in an on-premise Azure DevOps Server and I try to use a Publish Symbols task targeting the .pdb generated at build time. I also have a Symbol Server (a file share). When trying to use the resulting NuGet package, Visual Studio doesn't try to find the .pdb on the Symbol Server and doesn't try to download the correct source file.

I tried this with a dynamic library and everything worked fine.

Comment: Have you configured visual studio to use the symbol server?

Comment: yes, that's why I specified that with the dynamic library everything worked: VS found the pdb data in the symbol's server file share and using that data downloaded the right source file for debugging.

Comment: Could you share some details about your steps of packing,publishing the nuget package? Also the build pipeline definitions?

Answer (score 0):

PDBs created with static libs aren't meant to be used by the debugger directly, they can only be used by the linker. And the linker isn't able to find PDBs on a symbol server.

The only way, how the linker finds the .pdb files, is by using the information about the full path to the .pdb which was placed into the object file that was linked into the static lib. It then tries to find the .pdb file exactly at this location and as a fallback it also looks for the file with the same name in the location of the object file which was linked in.

When it can't find this .pdb file in any of both locations, then it just doesn't merge it into the resulting .pdb which the linker tries to produce for the current build step. If this build step was for an .exe project, which links your static lib in, this means the .pdb for this .exe, which can be used by the debugger, doesn't include any debug information of this library. The result is that you can't step into your lib code when you debug your .exe.

[/DEBUG (Generate Debug Info)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=msvc-170)

> You can also use the /Zi (Program Database) compiler option to store the debugging information in a PDB for the OBJ file. The linker looks for the object's PDB first in the absolute path written in the OBJ file, and then in the directory that contains the OBJ file. You can't specify an object's PDB file name or location to the linker.

[/Z7, /Zi, /ZI (Debug Information Format)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=msvc-170)

> If you create a library from objects that were compiled using /Zi, the associated PDB file must be available when the library is linked to a program. That means, if you distribute the library, you must also distribute the PDB file. To create a library that contains debugging information without using PDB files, you must select the /Z7 option. If you use the precompiled headers options, debugging information for both the precompiled header and the rest of the source code is placed in the PDB file.